# Names spacing JavaScript imports from native modules

Tags: javascript

I am migrating code that used to not use native JS modules.

```js
// File: form.js
// `lc` is a global object I attach each file's functions to.
let lc = window.lc || {}
lc.form = {};
lc.form.add = function() {
   // add a form
}
```

And then would be called as `lc.form.add()`, which is nice because the word `add` has context.

However now that I am changing the code to use JS modules:

```js
// File: form.mjs
export function add() {
   // add a form
}
```

And then would be called as `add()`, which has no context. Now I understand I could do:

```
import {add as formAdd} from '/form.mjs'
```

But thats like a step backwards to start smurf naming all imported things.

Is there a way to import the module like in Python, and then call functions of the modules. E.g. use dot etc notation to access it's function, something like this:

```js
import '/form.mjs' as form
form.add()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a namespace import:

```
import * as form from '/form.mjs';
form.add();
```

Comment: That is perfect, surprising nice syntax from JS! Happy days!

Comment: Its weird that `export default` is excluded from this way. `*` does not mean all as one would assume, has to be some sorta strange gotcha with JS.

Comment: Is it? I was pretty certain you could do `form.default`. It is ignored if you do `export * from …`, because there it would have a high chance of collisions with other default exports.